# Advanced search on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, search

Is it possible to restrict search results by user reputation? For instance, exclude question from users with reputation less than 9.

I found data.exchange where it is possible to query data with SQL syntax, but it works only with a replicated database.

Comment: No, it is not possible. A SEDE query is your only option. Or use the [StackAPI](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and filter the results your self

Comment: SEDE is a replicated database right? With one week old data?

Comment: Yeah, it gets refreshed on Sunday 03:00 UTC

Comment: You might like this userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/7496/reputation-based-filter-for-search-results

Comment: It's exactly that I was looking for. Thx!

Comment: What do you mean by "it works only with a replicated database"?

Comment: How is user reputation relevant?

Comment: Just to skip this kind of questions   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323202/show-the-number-of-product-and-display-vendor-code

Comment: 99% of malformed questions comes from users with reputation 1

Comment: The question title should be more explicit to help locating this duplicate: "Filter by user reputation in advanced search" or something like that - right now the title is totally bland.